# thread & block configuration requirements

Tags: cuda

I am developing a program in which I am calling a function which inputs random binary numbers.
The total number will be provided on run time eg: 1000, or 10,00,000..
And after generating the random numbers, I need to calculate total number of 0s and total number of 1s using COUNTERS.
I have the following queries:

1. How many threads, blocks & grids should I allot ?
2. Do I need 2D threads, or it can work with 1D thread only?
3. What function thread will do in it, I feel it should check whether particular value is 1 or 0 Does this sound right?
4. How should I use warps or tile method?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this might be a homework question, especially based on the only other question you've posted on SO.

1. How many threads/blocks/grids?  The answer to this question depends on your thread strategy.  What will each thread do?  For problems that produce a large amount of output, like image processing or matrix multiply, a common thread strategy is to assign each thread to do the work to create one output point.    But this problem only produces a small number of output values (2, it seems) and is in a category of problems including reductions, stream compactions, and histograms.  These problems are often solved in two steps (maybe 2 kernels...) and a common thread strategy (at least for the first step or kernel) is to assign one thread to each input point.  But see also my answer to 2 below.  Once you know how many threads you need, it's common to pick some number of threads per block like 256 or 512 (definitely use a power of 2), and then create enough blocks so that the number of threads per block times the number of blocks is equal to or larger than the problem size (number of input points in this case).
2. 2D or 1D?  Your problem isn't inherently 2D in nature, so a 1D grid of threads is a reasonable starting point.  However in a 1D grid of threads, the maximum number of threads you can create in the grid is limited to the max grid X dimension for the GPU you are using, times the number of threads per block.   These numbers are typically something like 65535 and 1024, so after about 64M elements of input points you'll run out of threads.  It's not hard to convert to using a 2D grid structure at this point, which will increase the number of possible threads to a size that is bigger than the GPU can handle at once.  However another strategy rather than switching to a 2D grid of threadblocks is to retain a 1D grid of threadblocks, but have each thread process multiple input points/elements, probably using a loop in your kernel code.  If your loop can handle up to 512 elements for example, then 65535x1024x512 should cover your problem size.  This is also a convenient thread strategy for this type of problem, because a thread can keep a local copy of the intermediate results it creates (the counts of ones and zeros so far) without interference or synchronization with other threads.
3. My suggestion based on the above is that a single thread would execute a loop, and each pass of the loop would look at an element, and update local variables that contain the counts of ones and zeros.    This would be the first part of a 2-part algorithm.  The second part would then have to collect these intermediate results.  You will want to give some thought to how the second part will collect the results from the first part.  For example, at the completion of the kernel, you may want to store the intermediate results back to global memory.
4. warps/tiling?  Warps refer to the grouping of threads into units of 32 threads for execution.  This will happen automatically for you.  You should arrange your algorithm such that when you are reading values from global memory (or writing values to global memory) that each thread reads (or writes) in a consecutive, contiguous block.  That is thread 0 reads from location 0, thread 1 from the next location, etc.  If you don't do anything unusual in your threads, this will happen more or less automatically for you.  The data storage created by cudaMalloc will be properly aligned, and if your array indexing strategy is something like a[thread_number] then you will get aligned and coalesced accesses across the warp, which is recommended to get good speed out of the GPU.  Tiling refers to a process of organizing data accesses to accentuate locality, which is usually beneficial for cache-dependent architectures.  If you do a good job of memory coalescing you won't be depending on the cache much.

If you can spare the time, the [CUDA C programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) is a very readable document and will expose you to the basic concepts needed for good GPU programming.  Also there are [webinars](http://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) on the nvidia web site which can cover the important material here in about 2 hours.  Also, [thrust](http://thrust.github.com/) can conveniently handle problems like this with a minimum of coding effort (in C++), but I'm guessing that's outside the scope of what you're trying to do right now.

Comment: When using the loop technique described in (3), you may have to take special care to get the coalesced memory accesses described in (4).

Comment: 1)@robert, understood well this part..i will take threads in a manner that will form more warps and multiply thread with blocks to get value which will be more than my entered value.
2)actually I dint understand, about 65535*1024*512?
3)For intermediate holding of results, _syncthreads() is ok?
but still dint understand, loop using thread??
I am confused, I want to use 1D only, then how should I approach this problem; 
Should i configure blocksize as of blockDim(256,1) for 256 threads in 1D am i right? 
i have read the book, but not finding approach to solve this problem,..please help me..

Comment: 65535*1024 is the maximum thread count in a 1D grid, at least for some GPUs.  If each thread contains a loop e.g. while(not_done) {process another input element} and if your loop can handle up to 512 points, then each thread can handle 512 points, and 512 points per thread * (65535*1024) max threads give the total number of input points you can handle using this method.  But the 512 loop count is arbitrary.

Comment: syncthreads() can be used to hold execution of a threadblock until all intermediate results from the threadblock are ready (perhaps for summing within the threadblock).  But you will need to gather multiple results from multple threadblocks.  Syncthreads can't help with that.

Comment: @Robert: thanks..
1)Even in my textbook it is written that "that this kernel can handle matrices uppto 16*65535 elements in each dimension & it can be divided into submatrices which will still be processed by an ample no. of blocks(65535*65535)" 
2)actually in my GPU, there are 14 Streamin procsr and each can handle upto 1536 threads...so how should I adjust the thread count 65535*1024 to work with my GPU? 
3)Does I need to do tiling for points 1, 2 and point you guided? 
4)How should I assign each thread a loop? requesting to explain..